# durandal knockout checkbox multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I have searched long for a solution but I can't find anything, so I asked you for help. knockout is getting this array from a ajax call:

```
[{"period_id":"2","room_id":"1","room_name":"CDI","room_description":"bla bla","days":[{"day_id":"1","day_name":"Montag"},{"day_id":"2","day_name":"Dienstag"}],"specials":[]}]
```

My problem here is the array `days` and a binding to check boxes in the view:

```
<td>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="monday" value="1" data-bind="checked: days['day_id']"> Montag
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" value="2" data-bind="checked: days['day_id']"> Dienstag
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" value="3" data-bind="checked: days['day_id']"> Mittwoch
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="thursday" value="4" data-bind="checked: days['day_id']"> Donnerstag
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="friday" value="5" data-bind="checked: days['day_id']"> Freitag
                </label>
            </td>
```

So I want, that a check box is checked, when value of the check box is in `days`. How would this be possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It will be helpful if you put this in jsfiddle, it is fine even if example is not working.

Answer (score 0):

databinding is usually about 2-way communication. What do you expect to happen if someone checks the checkbox?

If you just want a visual representation you can use comething like this

```
<!-- ko if: days[day_id] != null -->
// some green check image
  <img src="check" />
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: days[day_id] == null -->
// red cross image
   <img src="no check" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

also, you should make a viewmodel for your data and not try to interact too much with the result ofyour ajax call directly

for example

```
week: {
   monday: ko.computed(function() {
     return ko.utils.arrayFirst(days , function(day){ return day.day_id == 1;}) != null
     });
   tuesday: ... etc
}
```